# dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Cygenus_website.Models.images]'

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to retrieve image(varbinary(max)) and display it in view in my asp.net application:

Here's my action:

```
public ActionResult show_pics()
{
    DBEntities db = new DBEntities();
    var item = (from d in db.Images
                select d).ToList();
    return View(item);
}
```

And here's my view :

```
@model IEnumerable<Cygenus_website.Models.images>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "show_pics";
}
<h2>View_photos</h2>
<table>
    <tr>
       @foreach(var item in Model)
        {
            <td>
                @{
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.ImageBytes);
                    var imgsrc = string.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", base64);
                }
                <img src="@imgsrc" style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px" />
            </td>
        }
    </tr>
</table>
```

And I am getting error:

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'1[Cygenus_website.DAL.Image]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'1[Cygenus_website.Models.images]'.

I know I am Passing List to view() and model is of type enumerable but i don't know what to do?

Thanks.

Comment: You're passing the `Image` *entity* instead of the `Image` *view-model*. You'll have to map them.

Comment: I want to display all images in db how would i do that?

Comment: Change the view to `@model List<Cygenus_website.DAL.Image>` or map your data model to the view model

Comment: I changed the view but still getting error; can u tell me how to map data model to the view model? My image is stored as varbinary in sql db and now i want to display it in the web page.